# How to unit test a javascript function that ends in res.send(200, object)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous

I am trying to unit test the below function getAllPeopleFromDB:

```
export const getAllPeopleFromDB = async (req, res) => {
  const people = await getAllAustralianPeopleFromDB();
  res.send(200, people);
};
```

The issue is, I am not sure how to deal with the res.send(200, people) at the end.

Here is my attempt (this may or may not be useful):

```
  // datastoreService.getAllAustralianPeopleFromDB = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => (
  //   new Promise(resolve => resolve('stub'))
  // ));

  // describe('getAllPeopleFromDB', () => {
  //   test('that body contains people and has 200 status', (done) => {
  //     req = {};
  //     res = {};

  //     getAllPeopleFromDB(req, res).then((response) => {
  //       expect(response).toContain(['stub', 200]);
  //       done();
  //     });
  //   });
  // });
```

Comment: Make `res.send` a mock / spy / stub and verify that it is called with the expected data

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `.send` method on the `res` object, which accepts a data parameter (the data being sent) and stores it so its value can be checked. Your test code currently examines the data passed to `.then()`, which will be `undefined`, since `getAllPeopleFromDB` does not resolve a value.

Instead try:

```
describe('getAllPeopleFromDB', () => {
    test('that body contains people and has 200 status', (done) => {

        let responseData = ''
        const req = {};
        const res = {send: function(status, data) {responseData = data}};

        getAllPeopleFromDB(req, res).then(() => {
          expect(responseData).toContain('whatever');
          done();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: My eslint E6 syntax does not accept res = {send: (data) => responseData = data};

Comment: Just edited to try and stop ESLint from complaining (but I can only guess what your linter settings might be, so no guarantees).